# Refactoring if statements in python

Tags: python, if-statement, refactoring, code-cleanup

I would like to consult some piece of code with you. I have:

```
if tuple_type == Operation.START_SERVER:
    dictionary = ServersDictionary()
    dictionary.start(some_param)
elif tuple_type == Operation.STOP_SERVER:
    dictionary = ServersDictionary()
    dictionary.stop(some_param)
(...)
elif tuple_type == Operation.START_APP:
    dictionary = AppsDictionary()
    dictionary.start(some_param)
elif ...
(....)
```

And there I have 27 if / elifs. Normally, I would go into map - function dispatcher, but after every if / elif I have two lines of code with same *dictionary* reference. Would you suggest me some clean solution to replace those ugly constructions?

Creating 27 classes for applying polymorphism or 27 functions doesn't sound good... what do you think?

Comment: Use a hash table (a dictionary with methods as values)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But then I would need to create 27 functions. Is there any better solution?

Comment: You could use lambdas with statements seperated by `;`'s if you really needed to

Comment: are your `some_param`s different for all cases?

Comment: If the complexity is essential, the only question is where you want the complexity to appear. Yes, you can move it into a dict or a module or whatever but it is still there. If the complexity is not essential, then there is a pattern which allows you to simplify the complexity, but perhaps a cost for using the simplification -- such as being less flexible in the future.

Comment: Thanks! n9code- no, some_param is the same for all cases

Comment: Paul, what do you mean by complexity? I would rather make it as simple as it can be...

Comment: Of course you wanted it simple, but you couldn't do it, therefore you came here to ask question.  What if no one can make it more simple? What if it can't be any more simple to do the task correctly?  That is what I mean by "essential complexity"

Comment: @Konrad you can go with just updating your custom `Enum` class ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the meta info into your enums, if that is ok for you client code, meaning that you own the enums. Here is an example:

```
class Operation(Enum):
    START_SERVER = (0, "start", ServersDictionary)
    STOP_SERVER = (1, "stop", ServersDictionary)
    START_APP = (1, "start", AppsDictionary)
```

And then have a single function to handle your operations:

```
def handle_operation(operation, some_param):
    klass = operation.klass
    dictionary = klass()
    fn = getattr(dictionary, operation.value)
    fn(some_param)
```

This is assuming you are using the `Enum` you had in one of your questions. In that case, you will need to add one line there:

```
class Enum(object):
    __metaclass__ = EnumMeta

    def __init__(self, value):
        super(Enum, self).__init__()

        self.value, self.repr, self.klass = value[0], value[1], value[2]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.repr)
```

Then you will not need any case checks, simply:

```
handle_operation(tuple_type)
```

Comment: The function to call i assume - `self.klass = value[2]`

Comment: `operation.klass` is the `Enum` attribute (already updated the answer), which represents the class instance to be initialised for each operation type.

Answer (score 5):

You're right, a mapping is the way to go. Use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to access a method from its name:

```
mapping = {Operation.START_SERVER: (ServerDictionary, 'start', some_param),
           Operation.STOP_SERVER: (ServerDictionary, 'stop', some_param),
           Operation.START_APP: (AppsDictionary, 'start', some_param)}
...
cls, method, param = mapping[tuple_type]
dictionary = cls()
getattr(dictionary, method)(param)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can represent the operation with a dict or tupple, like

`op = {'target': 'Servers', 'action': 'start', 'params': (arg1, arg2)}`

then you can access it like

```
obj = globals()[op['target']+'Dictionary']()
getattr(obj, op['action'])(*op['params'])
```

Comment: Using `globals` is hackish